# Using XmlSerializer to create an element with attributes and a value but no sub-element

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

Hopefully this should be an easy answer for someone out there (and possibly a dupe), but I can't seem to figure it out.

I need to output an element that looks like this:

```
<Quantity foo="AB" bar="CD">37</Quantity>
```

I know how to get this:

```
  <Quantity foo="AB" bar="CD">
    <qty>37</qty>
  </Quantity>
```

with a Quantity class containing

```
public int qty;    
[XmlAttribute]
public string foo;

[XmlAttribute]
public string bar;
```

but then of course whatever variable I insert the quantity into becomes its own sub-element.

On the other hand, if I make the Quantity a variable in the parent element, then I can set the value and get

```
<Quantity>37</Quantity>
```

but then I don't know how to get the attributes.

I would be very surprised if there weren't a simple way to do this with XmlSerializer, but I don't know it yet. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xmlserializer - Control Element-Attribute Pairing (revised)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732314/xmlserializer-control-element-attribute-pairing-revised)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I find the answer here: [Xmlserializer - Control Element-Attribute Pairing (revised)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732314/xmlserializer-control-element-attribute-pairing-revised).

Here is how to do it: mark the value property with the [`[XmlText]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute.aspx) attribute.

```
public class Quantity {
  // your attributes
  [XmlAttribute]
  public string foo;

  [XmlAttribute]
  public string bar;

  // and the element value (without a child element)
  [XmlText]
  public int qty;

}
```

Comment: you answered your own question as well as mine.

Comment: It's a shame that the explanation for XmlText doesn't state anything about it being suitable for non-textual values

Comment: Just be aware `XmlText` is only suitable for non-complex types. I tried decorating an `object` type and got runtime errors.

Comment: @user3791372 Do you mean like CDATA?