# Deserialize C# from list string to object

Tags: c#, serialization

I need to deserialize a XML to an object, and i don't know how to convert a list of string in the XML to a list of object in the class.

I have this XML:

```
<Rack>
<Code>Code1</Code>
<SlotDtl>
  <Serial>010</Serial>
  <Serial>011</Serial>
  <Serial>012</Serial>
  <Serial>013</Serial>
</SlotDtl>....
```

And i need to create a list of Class slot:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public class Rack
{

    public string Code;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SlotDtl", typeof(Slot))]
    public List<Slot> SlotList;
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public class Slot
{
    public string Serial;
    public int Value;
    public int Record;
    public string Description;
}
```

But i don't know how to créate the list of object with the serialization tags.

Any Idea?

Comment: How do you want to bind `<Serial>010</Serial>` to your `Slot` object?  What will the `010` value be mapped to, and what should the other values be?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [Using XmlSerializer to create an element with attributes and a value but no sub-element](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3524289/3744182) but I can't say for certain unless you explain how you want to bind the `Slot` class to the `<Serial>010</Serial>` elements.